# Google Adsense not able to access Google Adsense code in website header, how to fix this?

Tags: adsense

My website([http://www.only4laugh.com](https://www.only4laugh.com)) is not WordPress based, I use JavaScript Framework (ReactJS) to build my website,  on connecting your website step google provide code to put in website header which is

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-8461898881815761" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

which I pasted on my website but Adsense still showing me Error
"Code is missing or incomplete"

Answer (score 0):

Well I need to use Nextjs for it using next/head solve my problem. Nextjs allow to render on serverSide before I was using React-Helmet which is causing issues, it showing metatags on header but not showing on browser first snapshot so I after replacing react-helmet to next/head it fix my issues.